# Растянуть 2 div'a по ширине

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Задача такова. Есть контейнер с фиксированой шириной. У контейнера есть 3 дочерних div'a с горизонтальним выравниванием. Размер каждого 33.3333%.   Вопрос в том, как растянуть 2 дочерних элемента если не пропадёт 1 дочерний на всю ширину родителя. Интересует только css решение.

Answer (score 3):

```css
html, body, section, div {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
}

div:first-child:hover ~ div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div style="background:red"></div>
  <div style="background:green"></div>
  <div style="background:blue"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если ширина фиксирована - то ничего сделать не получится. Получится, допустим, следующим образом:

```css
.parent {
  display:flex;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 32px auto;
  background-color: silver;
}
.child {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  flex: grow: 1;
  flex-flow: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 64px;
  margin: 8px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Попробуйте удалить один из дочерних блоков, КодПеро:

http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/ygddmG

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body, section, div {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
}

div:first-child:hover ~ div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div style="background:red"></div>
  <div style="background:green"></div>
  <div style="background:blue"></div>
</section>
```